# Casting type and converting

Tags: types, casting, type-conversion

What is the difference between these two methods? Both of them return the same type, which is `float`, but one use casting and the other does not.

```
public class Para1
{
    public float method1(int z)
    {
        return z;
    }

    public float method2(int z)
    {
        return (float) z;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The one is using implicit conversion from `int` to `float` and the other uses an explicit cast.  It amounts to the same thing in this case.

Comment: okay in this case when do we use casting, and which method is the perfect one to use and why? thanks

Comment: method2 is more readable, but none of them is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

The first function converts type *int* into type *float* implicitly. The second one does it explicitly. sometimes an explicit cast is required and Visual Studio cannot convert sophisticated types implicitly.

Comment: In the case of .NET, and C# in particular, it is not Visual Studio that cannot figure out how to convert the types. Type casts are explicitly defined as `operator`s, which the compiler will use based on whether they are defined to be [`implicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) or [`explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx).  The compiler will also not do more than one implicit step for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first function does *implicit* type conversion from `int` to `float`. The second does it as *explicit*.

Implicit type conversion is done by the compiler, explicit type conversion is done by the programmer.

For details see: [Type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)